# Python Recursive Function for Collatz Conjecture

Tags: python, recursion

I have written the following recursive program to show the number of steps a number goes through in Collatz Conjecture:

```
def cycle_length(n):
    count = 0
    if n == 1:
        return count
    if n%2 == 0:
        count += cycle_length(int(n/2)) +1
    elif n%2 != 0:
        count += cycle_length(int(3*n+1)) + 1
        print("The count is: ",count)
    return count 

print(cycle_length(22))
```

However the count is 15 when it should be 16. However, when I change the initial count to 1 or say:

```
return count + 1
```

It doubles the count to 31. I can't figure out what is causing this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `return count + 1` is not initial condition. It is return statement and it will change an even return value to odd one. And then whole program changes.

Comment: Not knowing what Collatz Conjecture is, I still find line `count += cycle_length(int(n/2)) +1` suspicious. The initial value of `count` is 0. Why not just return `cycle_length(int(n/2)) +1`? Is this what you expect to happen?

Comment: I changed the first if statement to `return count + 1` which seems to have solved it.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: Ah right yes Someone solved it but then deleted their solution. Should've posted my own I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `n` is 1, you need to increment `count` by 1 before returning it.

```
def cycle_length(n):
    count = 0
    if n == 1:
        return count + 1 # or simply return 1
    ...
```

But I think your code is syntactically correct if you do not choose to count the zeroth step.

See http://oeis.org/A070165.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making count=1, you should not do count+= in the later if, else if statements. Also, it seems to me that you earlier answer already correct. However, if you want to add 1 to it (i.e. counting the step when 1 occurs), just do the following:

```
 def cycle_length(n):
    count = 1
    if n == 1:
        return count
    if n%2 == 0:
        count = (cycle_length(int(n/2)) +1)
    elif n%2 != 0:
        count = (cycle_length(int(3*n+1)) + 1)
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

the Collatz sequence always start in the given number, therefore your base case should be return 1

that being said, you can also calculate it using iteration as python is not very fond of recursion, for example your code cannot calculate 9780657631 or 75128138247 without getting a recursion error

here is the iterative version

```
def collatz_length(n):
    if n<1:
        raise ValueError
    count = 1
    while n != 1:
        if n%2 == 0:
            n = n//2
        else:
            n = 3*n+1
        count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def cc(n):
    print(n)
    if(n%2==0):
        return cc(n/2)
    elif(n==1):
        return 1
    else:
        return cc(n*3+1)
print(cc(7))
```